# Prevent Windows 10 from accessing network shares with wrong credentials

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, smb

I have a NAS with a SMB share in my network. On my local machine (Windows 10) I haven't saved the credentials for the NAS. Now when I'm starting up, I can see in the access logs of the NAS, that it tries to access the shares using my Microsoft account, which results in a lockout of the IP address for 5 minutes.

How do I prevent Windows 10 from trying to access the share with wrong credentials?

I already tried `net use * /delete` and it says that there are no entries.

I guess I could disable auto network discovery alltogether, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Do you see anything in the registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network`? Can you decrease the 5-minutes black-list on the NAS?

Comment: @harrymc There is just the `(Standard)` key. Of course I could re-configure or even disable the lockout on NAS side, but I'd like to keep it as a security measure.

Comment: I don't have that on my computer. Does it contain anything interesting?

Comment: @harrymc I meant the `(Default)` entry. It's translated in German Windows version and I didn't notice. It has not value.

Comment: This is a feature of Windows for mapping the network, to my knowledge not possible to disable. Try instead to add a `$` at the end of the share-name, so perhaps Windows will think it's an administrative share.